# Why Threads have instruction pointer when methods are already stacked in LIFO manner?

Tags: java, multithreading, stack

Every `thread` has:

> - **Stack**: stores methods and local variables
> - **Instruction pointer**: keeps track of which instructions to execute next

My question is why is there `Instruction pointer` when methods are "stacked" in **LIFO** manner? So every time **method** that gets 'added' in `stack`, **last** method is **first** one to execute. So why is there need to instruction pointer when we already have a pattern for its behavior?

And is `instruction=method` in this context? To start with that :)

Comment: Instruction pointer points to the next instruction to be executed, not the next method. A method usually has many instructions. How you would know which instruction to execute next without an instruction pointer?

Comment: Instruction point can be thought of as pointing to lines inside the method.  Each method is executed in sequence, and the pointer tracks which one is next. (In reality the instruction pointer points to the byte codes, not lines, of course.)

Comment: (and more reality, the real instruction pointer is a machine register that points to the memory address of the machine instruction to be executed.  Since the address must actually be placed on the bus to load from a memory address, I'd say that the instruction pointer points to the current instruction, not the next.  However by the time that instruction executes, it usually is pointing to the next instruction because it's been incremented automatically.  In heavily pipelined architectures like i86, I'd imagine that the instruction pointer could be pointing much further down than that.)